# Angular: Problema recorriendo un objeto (array) definido en la clase AppComponent y con la directiva ngFor en html

Tags: angular, objeto, ngfor

Soy novato en Angular y TypeScript. Estoy siguiendo un curso tutorial y me encuentro con que el profesor utiliza en un video un ejemplo de inicialización de un objeto en un constructor de la clase AppComponent para utilizarlo posteriormente en un ejemplo de cómo se recorre con la directiva *ngFor. En su video funciona perfectamente pero yo hago lo mismo y me encuentro con el problema de que la propiedad "titulo" del objeto "entradas" no es visible en el código html.

Este es el error:

Error: src/app/app.component.html:53:53 - error TS2339: Property 'titulo' does not exist on type 'object'.

53     <li *ngFor="let entrada of entradas"> {{entrada.titulo}}

Y este es el trozo de la clase AppComponent :

```
export class AppComponent {
  title:string = 'Calculadora Angular';
  operador1:number=0;
  operador2:number=0;
  resultado:number=0;
  Positivo:boolean=false;
  signo:string="";

  nombre:string="";
  apellido:string="";
  mensaje:string="";
  registrado:boolean=false;

  entradas:object[];

  constructor(){
    this.entradas=[
      {titulo:"Python cada dia mas presente"},
      {titulo:"Java presente desde hace 20 años"},
      {titulo:"JavaScript cada vez mas funcional"},
      {titulo:"Kotlin potencia para tus apps"},
      {titulo:"¿Dónde quedó Pascal?"}
    ];
   ....
  }
```

Y esto el trozo de html que lo utiliza:

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let entrada of entradas"> {{entrada.titulo}}</li>
  </ul>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo mal es diciéndole que es un array de `object`, usa un tipo correcto o `any`

Comment: Pues en ese mismo video, abajo en los comentarios, está la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de utilizar `object`, puedes crear una interfaz

```
interface entradas {
    titulo:string
}
```

Y la llamas en tu código:

```
// Recomiendo que inicializes tu arreglo para no tener que comprobar si el 
// arreglo es nulo. 
entradas:entradas[] = [];

  constructor(){
    this.entradas=[
      {titulo:"Python cada dia mas presente"},
      {titulo:"Java presente desde hace 20 años"},
      {titulo:"JavaScript cada vez mas funcional"},
      {titulo:"Kotlin potencia para tus apps"},
      {titulo:"¿Dónde quedó Pascal?"}
    ];
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

He tenido exactamente el mismo problema que tú porque yo también estoy siguiendo el curso de Píldoras Informáticas.
La solución es sencilla, NO debes definir el Array de tipo Object. A mi me funcionó poniendo "any" en lugar de "object".

```
entradas:any[];
```

Comment: Si vas a usar tipo `any` entonces para que usas TypeScript? Debes evitar usarlo porque niegas la mayor ventaja de TS que es el tipado.

Answer (score -1):

trata de quitar el tipo `Object`, ya que TypeScript lo esta tomando como un dato tipo objeto, solo decláralo como un array vacío o crea la interfaz como dijo el compañero, ya que el `*ngIf` solo sirve para objetos iterables, y un objeto indefinido no se puede.

si te da error el array indefinido lo puedes solucionar con

```
entradas!= []
```